# Slow query performance in sqlite but sqlite studio reports fast execution

Tags: sql, sqlite, indexing, sqlitestudio

I have two large (~100 million rows) tables I'm trying to join.  I have indices on both columns used in the join.  Selecting the first 1000 rows takes several hours, but when it's done, SQLite Studio reports that it only took a minute.  Then, it takes another several hours for SQLite Studio to count the rows for my results and if I try to open another query window, it becomes unresponsive for these hours.  The entire time, task manager shows around 25% CPU usage and 7-8 MB/s disk usage for the process.  I also tried selecting the top 10k rows and it took 11 hours to complete and another 11 hours to get the row count, but reported that the query finished in 4 minutes.  Here is the query:

```
Select d.PRC, s.prccd, abs(abs(d.PRC)-s.prccd), *
from dsf d
join secd.secd s
on s.datadate=d.DATE and substr(s.cusip,1,8)=d.CUSIP
where abs(abs(d.PRC)-s.prccd)>.0006
limit 10000
```

1. Why is this taking so long?  I know 100 million rows is a lot, but with sorted indices, shouldn't joining happen in linear time?  Adding the indices took several minutes, not hours, and that should be O(n log n) since it has to sort.  I get the same results without using substr().  So why is it taking so long?
2. Why is SQLite Studio reporting that it only takes a minute or two?
3. Why does SQLite Studio take so long to count the result rows, after the results are already displayed?

EDIT:
Output of EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN

```
5   0   0   SCAN TABLE dsf AS d
7   0   0   SEARCH TABLE secd AS s USING INDEX secd_datadate (datadate=?)
```

Comment: Sounds like heavy job on actually reading data from disk. The query is resolved fast, but then it takes a long time to read bytes from the disk. At least it looks like it. How it works if you execute it **and display results** from official command line client `sqlite3.exe` (or `sqlite3` for Linux/Mac)?

Comment: Use [`EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN`](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) to see if it's actually using any indexes. Run [`ANALYZE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) if you haven't already.

Comment: @Googie What would cause that to happen and how can I fix it?  I'm running it in sqlite3.exe and it's been running for 10 minutes and has found one result, so looks like it's still slow.

Comment: @Shawn I ran PRAGMA optimize which should run analyze.  It didn't change the query plan.  I posted the results of EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN above.

Comment: Yeah, the table scan on `dsf` is killing it along with only one of the columns of `secd.secd` being indexed. I don't think there's a way to avoid the full scan on one of the tables since the `WHERE` uses columns from both tables. Hmm. Might play around with [indexes on expressions](https://www.sqlite.org/expridx.html) to see if you can get something that can be used to narrow down things in `secd.secd`, at least... `CREATE INDEX foo ON secd.secd(datadate, substr(cusip,1,8))` maybe, assuming that's accepted (I haven't tried).

Comment: An index on `dsf(date,cusip)` and a re-analyze might make it flip the order of the join, too, and scan `secd.secd` and search `dsf`, which may or or may not help.

Comment: (Oh, and a `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` gives you no guarantee about *which* rows will be returned)

Comment: @Shawn Adding that index does make is scan secd instead and use the new index.  It's a lot faster, like a few seconds instead of hours.  What's the general principle here and how can I fix stuff like this in the future?